# Excel Data Rearrange and Sorting, Unwanted Data in Row

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

I have data like this in file:

```
37/39   TOY-TRUCK#9588                      120 PCS
        PCKG: 60PCS/CTN/0.33                            

42-59   RECHARGE REMOTE CONTROL CAR#20181   216 PCS
        PCKG: 12PCS/CTN/0.18                            
        110v 2 FLAT PIN                         

        REMOTE CAR #B18                     192 PCS
        PCKG: 24PCS/CTN/0.21                            
        C/NO  92-97/99/101                          
117     REMOTE CARB13                       24  PCS
        PCKG: 24PCS/CTN/0.23
```

I want it to look like this when done:

```
        6PCS GLASS MUG SET       72 SETS
37/39   TOY-TRUCK#9588          120 PCS
42-59   RECHARGE REMOTE         216 PCS
        REMOTE CAR #B18         192 PCS
117     REMOTE CARB13            24 PCS
13-Apr  GIRL SHOE               400 PAIRS
```

Can anyone help me to get what i want with help of Macro or any formula.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like sorting by the third column will group all those rows with values together, then you can sort subsequently by any other logic you want.